# Get data from an API into SSIS Script Component Output Buffer

Tags: c#, ssis

I'm new in SSIS and I'm not very familiar with C#.

I was trying to achieve the following, as a similar work is in the pipeline in the next couple of weeks.

I have an online API **https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos**. It is having values in the following format.

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
}
```

I'm using a script component, added **Output** columns (all DT_STR), **userId**, **Id**, **title**, **completed**, I'm able to get the response from the API and store the response in a variable **result**. Please find the piece of code below.

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
   string url = String.Format("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
   WebRequest requestObject = WebRequest.Create(url);

   requestObject.UserDefaultCredentials = true;
   requestObject.PreAuthenticate = true;
   requestObject.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

   requestObject.Method = "GET";
   HttpWebResponse requestObject = null;
   responseObject = (HttpWebResponse)requestObject.GetResponse();

   string result = null;
   using (Stream stream = responseObject.GetResponseStream())
   {
      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
      result = sr.ReadToEnd();
      sr.Close();
   }
}
```

My aim is to store the result in the Script Component Output columns, using OutputBuffer.AddRow(), so that I can map them to an Oledb Destination.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/55229423/10376537

Answer (score 0):

In C#, define a class such as the following:

```
public class Value
{
    public int userId { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public Boolean completed { get; set; }
}
```

Then - after populating the result string with the response of your request - process the result string via JsonConvert:

```
List<Value> valueList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Value>>(response);
```

This done, you can loop through the list and push every value to its corresponding output. Following an example with Console.WritLine:

```
foreach (Value v in valueList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v.title);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tyron78, I've made the necessary changes in the code, but not being able to run the code. Install Newtonsoft.Json from Manage NuGet Packages and added using Newtonsoft.Json; in the Namespaces. The build is successfull, but, If I run the package, the script component fails with the following error, "Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference".